# Explicit computations of the fundamental groups of perfectoid spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

If $X$ is a perfectoid space then it has the same étale site as its tilt $X^\flat$. This means that the fundamental groups (suitably defined) of $X$ and $X^\flat$ are isomorphic.

Can you give interesting examples of computation of these fundamental groups (in the spirit of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114081/explicit-computations-of-the-%C3%A9tale-homotopy-type) question)?

For example Jannsen-Wingberg gave a description of the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for $p>2$ but $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of course is not perfectoid.

Comment: You might find this article of Weinstein interesting and relevant (http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/GQpAsFundamentalGroup/GQpAsGeometricFundamentalGroup.pdf). In this, he shows that the etale fundamental group of the ``punctured perfectoid open ball" quotiented by $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$ is $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$.